# Is the "always" sensor really always?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Upon running, my character immediately does its assigned task but when I press something for another object (that is my building shaking) my characters get pushed by the walls and will stop walking.

**Why does it stop when it's sensor is "always?"**

Answer (score 1):

An always sensor in it's default state sends one pulse at the beginning. If you want a continual pulse, activate pulse mode on the sensor.